# Laravel Command using DB::select

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a Command class that I can run with the artisan tool. I am able to get the command to fire from the shell, but when I use this code:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
```

It gives me an error of "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'".

If I run the same code from a regular controller, it works.

Is there a bootstrap routine that I need to run from inside the command as a precursor before using a class like DB?

**UPDATE:**

With seblaze's feedback, I was able to make this work by overriding the environment for artisan, as follows:

```
php artisan command:name --env=local
```

Comment: Did you made sure that the settings are not overwritten when you are using artisan ? ( check here : http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration )

Comment: Yep. That's the situation. I have a dev environment and artisan is loading the production environment. Thanks.

Comment: great ! i formatted a response, for further references to other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this works without any problem in a default Laravel installation .

Please check : 
You don't have any [overwritten default configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) 
And you have the correct user/password setup in your configuration.

Running artisan commands with database shouldn't be any issues.

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class CheckDB extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'checkmydb:db';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Check DB.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $results = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));

        $this->info($results[0]->email);

    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```